# Query multiple task lists in sharepoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I'm trying to query multiple task lists in SharePoint using:

```
SPSiteDataQuery query = new SPSiteDataQuery();
query.Lists = "<Lists ServerTemplate=\"171\" />";

query.Query = string.Concat("<Where>",
                                "<Neq>",
                                    "<FieldRef Name='Checkmark' />",
                                    "<Value Type='Calculated'>Completed</Value>",
                                "</Neq>",
                        "</Where>");

query.Webs = "<Webs Scope=\"Recursive\" />";
query.ViewFields = ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='AssignedTo' />";
SPListItemCollection dtTasks = web.GetListItem(query);

return dtTasks;
```

This doesn't work if AssignedTo field is set to UserMulti (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2703054).

I thought I could solve this by looping the lists (hardcoded into the code by title) and then collect the list item results:

```
  string[] listCollection = { "List1", "List2" };
  SPListItemCollection collection = null;

  foreach (var list in listCollection)
  {
      SPList spList = web.Lists.TryGetList(list);
      if (spList != null)
      {
          SPQuery qry = new SPQuery();
          qry.Query =
          @"<Where>
                  <And>
                      <Leq>
                          <FieldRef Name='DueDate' />
                          <Value Type='DateTime'>
                              <Today />
                          </Value>
                      </Leq>
                      <Neq>
                          <FieldRef Name='Checkmark' />
                          <Value Type='Calculated'>Completed</Value>
                      </Neq>
                      </And>
              </Where>";
           qry.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='AssignedTo' />";

           collection = spList.GetItems(qry);

      }

  }

  return collection;
```

But this of course overwrites the SPListItemCollection collection for each list.

How can I store the items from the lists for each iteration?

Comment: Not an answer, but why do you use "string.Concat" on constant strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a `DataTable` from your `SPListItemCollection` using `collection.GetDataTable()` and then merge the results into a single datatable using the `DataTable.Merge()` method.

```
foreach (var list in listCollection)
{
    var results = new DataTable();
    SPList spList = web.Lists.TryGetList(list);
    if (spList != null)
    {
        SPQuery qry = new SPQuery();
        qry.Query = "...";

        results.Merge(spList.GetItems(qry).GetDataTable());
    }
}
return results;
```

---

Alternatively, add the `SPListItem`'s from your queries to a new empty `SPListItemCollection` you've declared outside your foreach, as below. That way, you can access the items directly.

```
SPListItemCollection result = new SPListItemCollection();
foreach (var list in listCollection)
{   
    ...
    foreach (SPListItem listItem in spList.GetItems(qry)){
        result.Add(listItem);
    }
    result.Update();
}
return result;
```

Comment: web.GetSiteData(query) expects a SPSiteDataQuery, which "query" isn't because I have to use SPQuery instead.

Comment: I just realized the problem **is** `SPSiteDataQuery` which as you stated in your question can't handle `UserMulti.` I'll have a look later and see if it can be achieved otherwise.

Comment: Used your earlier suggestion as inspiration and solved it almost exactly like your update. Thanks a lot Daniel B :)

Comment: You know if it's possible to access the items url in some way? When I'm using DataTable (and then looping the results with DataRow, cannot use SPListItem). I only can find a few item properties in item.ItemArray.

Comment: Perhaps it would be wiser to skip the `DataTable` alltogether and instead create an empty `SPListItemCollection` outside your loop, and then inside the loop iterate over each `SPListItem` and add it to your outer `SPListItemCollection`. That way you can keep the items as `SPListItems`.

Comment: Not really sure what you mean.. How do I add SPListItem to the SPListItemCollection when I loop the results from the query? If thats what you mean.

Comment: I added my alternative answer.